# Should item(s) be followed by is or are?

Tags: grammar

When the plurality of an item is unknown, the convention is to put (s) after the item. In

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The subject "item" followed by a conjugation of the verb "to be" would obviously require "is," while "items" would obviously require "are." But you seem to be driving at some use of "item" without an S when it's known to actually be plural, something you need to provide examples of.

Comment: Speak it aloud and write whatever you say.